# Why could the solution returned by the SciPy `minimize` method be worse than from a specific call to the objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to minimize a function with the SciPy `minimize` method.

I'm running into a situation where the returned solution from `minimize` is *worse* than the solution from certain calls to the objective function during the execution of `minimize`. I ran my program through a debugger with a breakpoint at the end of the objective function, and saw that the value returned for some calls was smaller than the value that was obtained when the objective function was called with the input being the solution returned by `minimize`.

The solver I'm using is `SLSQP` with an `ftol` of `1e-10` and bounds of (-5, 5). I let the solver compute the gradient numerically.

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is an optimal control problem where the goal is to move a pendulum to a certain position and velocity in as little time as possible by applying a torque on the pendulum.

Why didn't `minimize` return the solution from one of the calls to the objective function where the value was smaller?

Comment: This is not enough info. `minimize` is a wrapper for multiple different solvers, including *constrained* ones (where this behaviour is not too surprising). But the question lacks all details: which problem, which optimizer, which objective, which constraints, numerical diff vs. given gradient/hessian?

Comment: I guess you will have to show us the example, otherwise it is close to impossible to help.

Comment: Added some more details.